# How to design a multi tenant mysql database in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, multi-tenant

I am looking forward to setup a Multi tenant database model on mysql. One database with multiple schemas.

I am attaching a screenshot, i created this in phpMyAdmin, i am not sure what is schema here and what is database, Can you help me decode this?

Is the box icon schema and cylinder icon database?

[image: Screenshot]